# No such file or directory when piping from request in Node

Tags: node.js

I need to request a .zip file from a URL then pass the contents to [AdmZip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip)

When attempting to pipe the output of the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library:

```
const zipFilePath = path.join(batchPath, this.zipFile.filename);
const out = fs.createWriteStream(zipFilePath);

const req = request.get(this.zipFile.url);
req.pipe(out);
req.on('end', function() {
  console.log("I should be here, but I'm not");
});
```

I receive:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\Brandon\work\keystone4-projects\html-email\batch-content\5996588a3bc30010502bfa9e\test.zip'

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I added:

```
if (!fs.existsSync(batchPath)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(batchPath);
}
```

before attempting to pipe the output and my function completed successfully.

Comment: Did you check that the directory structure leading up to the destination filename exists?

Comment: Everything up to "C:\Users\Brandon\work\keystone4-projects\html-email\batch-content\" is correct. I'm betting I have to create the directory "5996588a3bc30010502bfa9e"... correct?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, yes. Node will not perform any kind of implicit 'mkdir -p'-like behavior when writing files.

Comment: That was it. I'm not sure why I didn't think of that before...too tired. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when you receive this error when *writing* a file, it means that the path leading up to the file being written does not exist.